# Website Header appears different in Safari compared to Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

i'm making a website on my windows PC and I notice that the header doesn't look right in safari on a mac but works in Chrome. I don't have a mac for developing and would like to know what it is I need to fix. You will notice that there is a gap between the header and the slideshow and an issue with the page heading.

here is the website, temporarily part of my portfolio website while it's being developed: http://wjhdevelopment.uk/Shed%20-%20New/index.html (excuse the bad url for now)

Also if anyone has any good methods of developing for safari on windows that would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> you can use javascript, if browser is safari so do this.

```
 var a = navigator.appname
    var b= navigator.appversion
if(a==safari){
css code for changes in webside
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your .header height. Also your .content top and margin-top.

Your header is bigger than 150 so you don't need that. And without the height limit your content fixes also become obsolete.